# Tableau -- find total sales of the month

Tags: tableau-api

I have date-wise data of a month in Tableau and I want to know total sales of the month. Can anyone show how to do it?

Here is the snapshot of the issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would advise you to go to the "Data Source" Panel on the bottom left and change the data type of the dimension "Date" to date instead of string. If this is not possible, please speak with your datasource admin. It might be a problem, that the dates are in different formats (like "1.07.06" and "1.11.2016").

[image]

After that you can simply choose the discrete MONTH(Date) dimension by rightklicking (blue pills). If you display data ranging over different years it is advised to keep the "YEAR(Date)" blue pill.

In the sample data it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to get total sales month wise**

1. Drag your date into column shelf and change by Right click on date and change into month.
2. Drag sales into row shelf and Right click on measure and go into sum.so you will get total sales per month.